# Interpreting Leibnitz's "Law Of Continuity"

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

For my personal reason, I have to write a blog which tries to explain about the symbols of the differential as well as the integral. In that process, I hit upon the Leipnitz's ["**Law Of Continuity**",](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Continuity), where I found his word as it is in the link **"whatever succeeds for the finite, also succeeds for the infinite"**. And somehow or someway, I started thinking philosophically, and my personal conculsion came to this. **"Anything that stops at some point, has the unspoken ( or unconditional ) --- potential --- that --- could reach --- or -- continue -- to the infinite"**???? Am I right or is there any more implication about his word???? **Or should I consider,** his word implies that **there is actually no Zero?????** I am totally perplexed but somehow very curious about his word. Thank you in advance for any answer or comment..

Comment: Kindly think I am quite unknowledgeble about math. I am very sorry.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I cannot see how your statements : "Anything that stops at some point, has the potential to continue to the infinite" and "LofC implies that there is no Zero" are related to Leibniz's Law... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Continuity) :

> the *Law of Continuity* is a heuristic principle introduced by Gottfried Leibniz

used by him to "motivate" is new *infinitesimal calculus*.

> Leibniz used the principle to extend concepts such as arithmetic operations, from ordinary numbers to infinitesimals.

It is an "heuristic principle" because it is not true without exception :

> Leibniz adequately summed up the true meaning of his law, stating that "the rules of the finite are found to succeed in the infinite."

This is not true e.g. for [transfinite arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number).

---

You can see [Continuity and Infinitesimals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/#4).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please kindly let me have time to read and think with an apology. I am sorry.

Comment: I am sorry to say like this, but I am too unknowledgeable to judge if yours is "truly" correct after reading the link so kindly allow me to take yours as the answer! I am sorry!

Comment: I am sorry. But after having read the link you provided, I got more perplexed. Ordinals or not, what is the term **transfinite number** different from what Leipnitz said??? All the way down, all the people who are appearing here ( including the link ) are just talking about the **possibility** to the infinite. So, since it is after all the **possibility**, **should I dismiss it just as some kind of stuff like Heaven**, which after all **WE DO NOT KNOW**??????????

Comment: @KentaroTomono - Leibniz did not know about *transfinite* numbers. He applied his principle to heuristically justify the extension of some algebraic laws (validated for *finite* numbers) also to "infinitesimals". The issue is : we have "discovered" new numbers, like the transfinite ones, and in this case the principle does not hold in general; see e.g. :  ω +1 =  ω.

Comment: **In mathematics**, there is **0**, *infinite* and also "infinitesimals", but there is **no** Heaven. Outside math ... I do not know.

Comment: I see....thank you. I think it takes me for a while to understand itself your commnet...thank you anyway.

Comment: I understood that there is definitely zero, and **infinitesimals**. Now, I am sorry to say like this, what on the earth differentiates in the verrrrryyyyyyy fundamental meaning, the **infinitesimals** from what Leipniz said?????????????? The **infinitestimals** is the **unmesurably small**, which is to me, looking like being equivalent with what Leipnitz said?, which is, **"whatever succeeds for the finite, also succeeds for the infinite"**, yes, if there is the **infinitestimals**, then he was **RIGHT**, because, **whatever tries to reach to the finite, also has the infinite**

Comment: = the **infinitestimals**. It looks like this does not belong to the philosophy.................................